# How to create c exe on unix box

Tags: c, cs50

When I run `make`, I get a file with no file type. Is there a way to create a `.exe` file that I can just click on in Windows to run?

I installed in my home directory:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

but when I run from ~/workspace/pset2/vigenere:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o vigenere.exe vigenere.c
```

I get:

```
vigenere.c:1:18: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
#include <cs50.h>
```

Using clang:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror $1.c  -lcs50 -lm -o $1
```

how do I find the location of `-lcs50` and add it to my path?

Comment: You're trying to include a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: `cs50.h` isn't avialable in your include search-parth.

Comment: using clang: clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    $1.c  -lcs50 -lm -o $1 how do I find the location oc -lcs50?

Comment: Did you install this cs50 library?

Comment: yes, and using clang it works fine.  I also added both the cs50.h and cs50.c files to the vigenere folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error that will not produce an executable. The file `#include <cs50.h>` which you have included is not in the system include directories. You probably meant `#include "cs50.h"`, which will search the current directory. When you have fixed all the errors, just type `./vigenere.exe`. The `.exe` is typically not included in UNIX.